# Haskell : Problem converting result of division to integral type

Tags: haskell, typeclass, division, collatz

I'm learning Haskell and stuck trying to understand the type system.

I'm trying to write a function which returns the length of the series 'Half or Three Plus One' for an input. Here's my attempt at the function, using a recursive approach (the function is valid for integral inputs only):

```
hotpo :: (Integral a) => a->a
hotpo n = hotpoHelper n 1

hotpoHelper:: (Integral a) => a->a->a
hotpoHelper 1 n = n
hotpoHelper num count
    | even num = hotpoHelper (truncate (num/2)) (count+1)
    | otherwise = hotpoHelper (3*num+1) (count+1)
```

Here is the error I get when I try to load this file in GHC 6.12.3

```
test.hs:8:30:
    Could not deduce (RealFrac a) from the context (Integral a)
      arising from a use of `truncate' at test.hs:8:30-45
    Possible fix:
      add (RealFrac a) to the context of
        the type signature for `hotpoHelper'
    In the first argument of `hotpoHelper', namely
        `(truncate (num / 2))'
    In the expression: hotpoHelper (truncate (num / 2)) (count + 1)
    In the definition of `hotpoHelper':
        hotpoHelper num count
                      | even num = hotpoHelper (truncate (num / 2)) (count + 1)
                      | otherwise = hotpoHelper (3 * num + 1) (count + 1)
```

`take (truncate (5/2)) [1,2,3]` works, so I'm unable to understand this error message.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/` operator in Haskell is used for floating point division.  If you really did want to use floating point division and `truncate`, you'd use `fromIntegral` on `num` first to convert it to a floating point number.  The error you get is saying that you can't use fractional division on an integral number (5/2 works because the compiler infers a floating point type for both numbers).  However, you can do what you want much more easily, using the `div` function.  This is typically used infix, by surrounding the function name with backquotes (this works for any Haskell function):

```
| even num = hotpoHelper (num `div` 2) (count+1)
```